# Xcode automatically prefixing file names

Tags: ios, xcode

Since Xcode 6.2 it wants to prefix a filename with its type.

So a "Test" UIViewController now is named:

UIViewController+Test.h,
UIViewController+Test.m

rather than Test.h, Test.m.

I have tried 6.3 and 6.4 beta and they all exhibit this habit. How do you stop it?

Many thanks.

Comment: That's a `UIViewController` extension class, are you choosing the proper file (CocoaTouch Class) when adding it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You created a category, not a class.

When you use the “Objective-C File” template, you can create an empty file, a category, a protocol, or a class extension. You cannot create a class using the “Objective-C File” template. Here's what it looks like when you create a category:

[image: creating a category]

To create a class, you need to use the “Cocoa Class” template. Here's what it looks like when you create a class:

[image: creating a class]

Answer (score 2):

It will automatically add the class name as a prefix for categories, if that's what you mean:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Select `IOS -> Source -> CocoaTouch Class` and the select `UIViewController` then write your class name Test by removing `UIViewController`  which is alrady present in `class name`. If you write your `class name` first then select `UIViewController`   then it will appear attached with your `class name`